# Can multiple services use one Relying Party?

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-oauth, openid, openid-connect

My company are going to use OpenID connect and use Google as Identity Provider, I have read OpenID connect document these days, still have some questions, first one is we have multiple services, should we create Relying Party for each service, or can use create one Relying Party for all our services?

For example, company site: `company.com`, and 3 completely different services: `service1.com`, `service2.com`,`service3.com`, so should we provide 3 Relying Party: `auth.service1.com`, `auth.service2.com`,`auth.service3.com`, so if user click `login` button on `service1` which points to `auth.service1.com` will redirect user to `account.google.com`.

Or can we just provide 1 Relying Party, `auth.company.com` for all 3 services?

Answer (score 1):

First understand what **relying party** means in OpenID Connect (OIDC) context. From the [**specification**](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Terminology),

> **Relying Party (RP)**
>
> OAuth 2.0 Client application requiring End-User Authentication and
> Claims from an OpenID Provider.

RP is a OAuth 2.0 client. So if you check OAuth 2.0 specification for it's definition, you find below [**definition**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1) (extracted, see the full description from link),

> An **application** making protected resource requests on behalf of the
> resource owner and with its **authorization**

As I see, answer relies in those highlighted points.

- Can each services can be categorise as an application independently? Do they have independent behaviour from each other?
- How authorisation constraints act on these services. Do they have independent functionalities? How they represent the end user (resource owner) ?

So if you consider each service as an independent application and have its own authorisation constraints, then I think they should consider going for different RPs. Else if these services are dependent with each other and internally use same authorisation constraints, then go for a single RP to represent them.

Regardless, it's difficult to answer correctly without exactly knowing what those services actually do.

Comment: Thanks, yes ,these services are completely different. Only same thing is going to use Google as Auth. But since these services are all belong to one company, we don't like to develop each RP for each service, just want to confirm if we can just develop one RP for all these services?

Comment: @Sato It's difficult to answer without the knowledge of these services. But if you develop one RP for all three services, then you will access all services with a single token. Which means if you login to one service A , you can use same access token from login A for service B and C too. There are security considerations in that aspect. But again you may control such with scope parameter. So that a single login will only allow you to consume one service. All these must be considered when you make a choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You just need some custom code in your RP to manage requests from multiple apps if logic differs. This also provides a place to abstract logic away from clients and avoid code duplication.